# WooCommerce category pages messed up after theme update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have recently updated a client's Wordpress website with the newest version of the theme Avada along with the latest WooCommerce. There is a lot of bespoke code and styling in here but all within the theme folder which was copied over post-update.

However, although everything seems OK elsewhere, the category listing page (and also the related products within the product detail pages) look completely messed up, as if the div surrounding the unordered list has disappeared, making the whole page look odd.

Here is an example of what I mean: http://loveandfun.co.uk/product-category/rabbit-range/

As you can see, the first product in the category list is fine, but then the ul is closed and the rest of the products are shoved underneath completely outside of the loop it seems. I cannot find any reason why this would have happened, so I am a little stumped.

Can anyone shine a light on why this may have happened?

Thank you.

Comment: That's not nearly enough information for us to help you. It looks like the theme's CSS for list items changed. You should be able to make the appropriate CSS fixes in your child theme.

Comment: Yes I understand that some CSS has changed, but all of the CSS edits were done via the Custom CSS module within the Wordpress admin. I'm assuming it is a WooCommerce file that would have done this, I just cannot find which one. I can't imagine that CSS would close a div or ul prematurely.

Comment: Kindly, the best way for premium themes (updates issues) is to contact first theme author through support threads (or opening a support ticket)… They are in much better position to help you… After, if you still get a problem, Its very difficult to help without the possibility to get logged as admin, into your back end…